# Jquery or ajax to php function without reloading page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a php page that i call a calendar class function to show the calendar. which is just

```
$calendar->show(true);
```

It has another function that lets you call it by

```
$calendar->show('July 2015')
```

So what i am trying to do is create a header on top that shows next and previous and then have it be a link, but i am trying to figure out how i can click on the previous link that when i click on it, just reruns the function with the date specified instead of reloading the whole page again and using url parameters. I've been looking into ajax and jquery, it seems possible, but it only shows how to post to a php page. I can't find a way to just rerun a function if thats even possible.

Comment: include more code: HTML / JS / PHP

Comment: You will HAVE to make an ajax request if you want to fetch some data without reloading the page.

Answer (score 0):

you need code like this:
HTML:

```
<div id='next' class='year'></div>
<div id='next' class='month'></div>
<div id='prev' class='day'></div>
<div id='date'></div>
<div id='next' class='day'></div>
<div id='next' class='month'></div>
<div id='next' class='year'></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.day, .month, .year').click(function() {
var a = $(this).attr('id'); // find prev or next clicked
var b = $(this).attr('class'); // find day or month or year clicked
$.ajax({
type: 'post',
url: //your php url,
data: {act: a, which: b, /* your other data */},
cache: false,
success: function(c) {
$('#date').html(c);
}
}):
});
```

and PHP:

```
<?php
include //your class
echo $calendar->show('$_POST['data']')
?>
```

Comment: no way, to just rerun the function itself without re posting to the site?

Comment: @BradHazelnut If implemented correctly, you can use this AJAX to execute only the desired function and then reload a very targeted HTML element (like a div) with the results returned by the function. It's not "re posting" in the sense you are thinking.

Comment: you want receive data without sending request to server?!! it's impossible.